# Trapezium: length of a line of segment

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[Trapezium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAHuz.png)

In the figure PQRS is a trapezium with PQ parallel to SR.

The diagonal of the trapezium meet at X.

U lies on SP and T lies on RQ such that UT is a line segment through X parallel to PQ.

The length of PQ is 12 cm and the length of SR is 3 cm.

What, in centimetres, is the length of UT?

I tried to use the Thales theorem but I did not get a solution. I read a lot of about properties of trapezium but I couldn't find any useful information. So I need some guidance. Which property or theorem can be used for this question.

Comment: Please I need help to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show us your trying.

Comment: I tried to use the Thales theorem but I did not get a solution. I read a lot of about properties of trapezium but I couldn't find any useful information. So I need some guidance. Which property or theorem can be used for this question.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{UX}{12}=\frac{SX}{SQ}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{XQ}{SX}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{12}{3}}=\frac{1}{5}.$$
Thus, $$UX=2.4.$$
By the same way we can get $$TX=2.4,$$ which gives the answer:
$$UT=2\cdot2.4=4.8.$$

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. I knew that I had to use Thales theorem but I did not figure out that I could write SQ as SX + XQ and carry out the division by SX.                   
Thank you once more.